# Using nested function

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a nested function in xcode. What am I doing wrong?

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
            print("Worked")
        }

    }
```

I am expecting my code to print "Worked" when the segue happens. It is not printing.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a nested function?

Comment: Because I want to get the "indexPath.row" from the didSelectRowAt and use it in the prepare function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare` method is a method of `UIViewController`. You need to properly override it. This means it can't be a nested function. It needs to be top-level method of your view controller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("Worked")
}
```

If you need access to `indexPath` in `prepare`, you need to pass it, not `self`, as the `sender` parameter.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("Worked")
    if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
        // do stuff with indexPath
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to get the array data from the tableview and use it in the prepare function. How would I do that without nesting them, because I cant create a variable in the didSelectRowAt function and use it in the prepare function.

Comment: Your array is a property of the class, right? Access it like you are probably doing in several of your other existing methods of your class. If you need the indexPath, pass that as the sender, not `self`.